# Empty value inserted in sql server on asp.net with required field validator provided

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

Can you please explain why empty value inserted in sql server on asp.net
  with the validations(eg: required field validator) provided?
  Though the sql table column types is varchar, so in stored procedures the parameters also defined as varchar but not null.
  But for some records these fields are inserted as empty value (Not 'NULL')

**Added from comment below**

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="23"
                    EnableSingleInputRendering="False" 
                    CssClass="signuptxt"> 
  <EnabledStyle Width="250px" /> 
  </telerik:RadTextBox> 
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" runat="server"
                                ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" 
                                ErrorMessage="First Name is required" 
                                ToolTip="First Name is required" 
                                ForeColor="Red" 
                                ValidationGroup="regcust">*
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

  <telerik:RadButton ID="btnRegister" class="submit" type="submit" runat="server" Text="Register Customer" Width="210px" Font-Size="Large"
                                    Skin="buttonRed" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" ValidationGroup="regcust" OnClick="btnRegister_Click">
                                </telerik:RadButton>
```

Comment: Well does your validator require the value to have a particular minimum length? Please show *exactly* what validation you're applying - perhaps an empty string is deemed a valid value?

Comment: The `RequiredFieldValidator` will only validate as false if the control being validated has a different value than it's `InitialValue` - so if someone hits the space bar in the TextBox and then moves to another input, it will evaluate as valid.

Comment: @Sanooj can we see your c# code? maybe you placed your StoredProcedure in a different place making it insert first the values before Asp can validate it.

Comment: @Tim - I did test with Space bar, but still it evaluate as invalid entry both localhost and published version

Comment: @DanzaiVer - The stored procedure calls only in the button click event.So this event fires only the validation passed.Also this happens only few times for some record insertion.

Comment: @Sanooj can we see your button please , i want to see if `cause validation` is set to true and if there you have provided `Validation Group`

Comment: @suraj singh - Check the modified question to view the button details

Answer (score 0):

Use `Page.IsValid` in your server side code to verify your client validation is working also try using regular expression validator for blank spaces. It would be better if you could add an empty entry check in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `causesvalidation="true"` to your button .

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnRegister" class="submit" type="submit" causesvalidation="true"  runat="server" Text="Register Customer" Width="210px" Font-Size="Large"
                                        Skin="buttonRed" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" ValidationGroup="regcust" OnClick="btnRegister_Click">
                                    </telerik:RadButton>
```

A submit button will always submits the `form` , It's default behavior ,so no matter what it will submit your form ,try using `return false;` on `OnClick` . It will stop form to do its default behavior . 
I have zero knowledge about `telerik` so i am just suggestion on the basis of what i know hope it works for you . :-)